# Getting an error when trying to create a Fragment from a Xamarin Forms ContentPage

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use Xamarin Forms Embedding to share XAML ContentPages across multiple native projects. I have added the latest Nuget Xamarin.Forms to all projects and this all compiles fine. I get a runtime error that says "element is not of type Xamarin.forms.view" on the call to CreateFragment.  Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Here is my ContentPage which sits in an old fashioned PCL (created before .NET Standard projects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="commonClassLibrary.ContentPages.MainScreen">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                <Label Text="Wowzers" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the layout my MainActivity is using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/container" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here I am trying to swap in the Fragment created from my ContentPage:

```
        if (!Xamarin.Forms.Forms.IsInitialized) {
            // initialize Xamarin.Forms before we use it
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        }

        // create the login page (Xamarin.Forms ContentPage)
        var main = new MainScreen();

        // get hold of the native Android fragment that represents the Xamarin.Forms page
        var mainFragment = main.CreateFragment(this);

        // show the login screen (native Xamarin.Android)
        FragmentManager
            .BeginTransaction()
            .AddToBackStack(null)
            .Replace(Resource.Id.container, mainFragment)
            .Commit();
```

Comment: Create Android view in Xamarin.Forms? It can't be reached.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean.  What I'm trying to do is embed a Xamarin Forms contentpage into a Xamarin Android app.  It was a new feature I believe in XF 3.0.

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Nope, I just abandoned it.  I'm gonna have to just build the ui in each native head.